# Is there a way to display at least 10 modal windows on single click?

Tags: php, html, css

I use this code to display modal whenever the user clicks the button.

```
<a href='#awesome' data-toggle='modal'><input type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-primary' value = 'Click Here' > </a>
.... </html>

<div class='modal fade' id='awesome' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog' style='width: 600px;'>
    <div class='modal-content' style=''>
        <div class='modal-header'>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-body' style = 'height: 500px;  background-image:url(bground.jpg);  background-repeat: no-repeat; ' >

        </div>

        <div class='modal-footer'>
        <!--<a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way or function to display at least 10 modals with different positions on screen in just one click?

Comment: uhh...why would you want to display 10 modals at once?

Comment: so you want to annoy the user?

Comment: Yes, there is. You even have tens of thousands. The code will need to 'clone' the modal DOM elements so each modal window has it's own DOM nodes (and thus displayed 'window'/content). That is, the *HTML modal windows are naught by DOM elements 'displayed on top'*, perhaps with an overlay..

Comment: There actually isn't a way. They've tried over and over to achieve this, but the current theory is that it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using Jquery.

Assuming the button has an id of 'modalOpen'
You can write:

```
$('#modalOpen').click(function(){
  $('.modal1').show(function(){
      $(this).css('top', '100px');
  });
  $('.modal2').show(function(){
      $(this).css('top', '200px');
  });
  ....
});
```

This way you can add as many modals you want which will open when the user clicks on the button with ID 'modalOpen'

Comment: Why is there a downvote? I don't see any better way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, you could clone/create the DOM elements programatically so you don't have to have 10 duplicate nodes in the HTML as this is suggesting (which is less than ideal). Both jQuery (and many common dialog frameworks) provide a built-in method of 'cloning' the target element.